# Form fields are not present on the form object in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have the following code from [angular site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-):

```
<form name='form'>
    <div contentEditable="true" ng-model="content" title="Click to edit">Some</div>

    <pre>{{form | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

I outputs the following thing below the desired input:

```
{
  "$error": {},
  "$name": "form",
  "$dirty": true,
  "$pristine": false,
  "$valid": true,
  "$invalid": false,
  "$submitted": false
}
```

Sadly I can't check the validity/ditryness/etc of the input as there is no input property on the form.

**Why are the field not present on the form object in angular?**

[Relevant plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YhkCrWV1gQKOsUxS94Rt?p=preview)

Angular version: **1.4.4**

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that a property is added to the form object **only** *(relates to reasonable changes only in HTML)* when the `name` attribute of the input is present.

Thus this code (I've added `name='firstName'` and some basic validation : `ng-required="true"` for sake of test):

```
  <form name='form'>
    <div contentEditable="true"
         ng-model="content"
         title="Click to edit"
         ng-required="true"
         name='firstName'> Some </div>

    <pre>{{form | json}}</pre>
  </form>
```

Will output the form object with the `firstName` property related to input:

```
{
  "$error": {},
  "$name": "form",
  "$dirty": true,
  "$pristine": false,
  "$valid": true,
  "$invalid": false,
  "$submitted": false,
  "firstName": {
    "$viewValue": " Some ",
    "$modelValue": " Some ",
    "$validators": {},
    "$asyncValidators": {},
    "$parsers": [],
    "$formatters": [],
    "$viewChangeListeners": [],
    "$untouched": false,
    "$touched": true,
    "$pristine": false,
    "$dirty": true,
    "$valid": true,
    "$invalid": false,
    "$error": {},
    "$name": "firstName",
    "$options": null
  }
}
```

[Relevant plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iyYtkIf9UJJTj9j2hOAA?p=preview)